# xamarin creating a tablelayout with 2 buttons on each row

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, tablelayout

i've been trying to create a Table Layout with 2 buttons next to eachother. i've been reading around, however i can't seem te get it to show anything on the screen. this is my current code for the TableLayout.

```
TableLayout ll = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.buttonLayout);
        TableLayout llInner = new TableLayout(this);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        llInner.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        llInner.LayoutParameters = lp;
        llInner.WeightSum = 2;
        ll.AddView(llInner);
        var i = 0;
        var row = new TableRow(this);
        //TableRow.LayoutParams rowlayout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MatchParent, TableRow.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        row.LayoutParameters = lp;

        foreach (var series1 in series)
        {
            var b = new Button(this);
            b.Text = series1.Series;
            //lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(1, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            b.LayoutParameters = lp;
            row.AddView(b);
            i =+ 1;
            if (i > 1)
            {
                llInner.AddView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent));
                row = new TableRow(this);
                row.LayoutParameters = lp;
                i = 0;
            }
        }
```

any suggestions?

thanks in advance,

Bjorn

Comment: Hi there, why don't you try to use .axml pages. In Xamarin traditional and Xamarin forms design page is opmitise. And very useful.

Comment: sinds the amount of buttons needed to be created is dynamic sinds it is based on information i recieve from an API. therefore i don't know how many buttons i will need to create.

Answer (score 1):

> i've been trying to create a Table Layout with 2 buttons next to eachother.

Just from your code, besides the original `TableLayout` named `buttonLayout`, you created another `TableLayout` and a `TableRow`, and then added `Button` controls into this row, but you never add this row to the view of your `TableLayout`, and you need to pay attention to the `LayoutParams`, you used a `TableLayout.LayoutParams` for all controls, but inside it is the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, that's not right.

Since I don't have your `series`, I can't really understand what you're doing in `foreach`, here I just post a sample code:

```
TableLayout ll = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.buttonLayout);

ll.WeightSum = 2;
ll.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MatchParent, TableRow.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
row.LayoutParameters = lp;

var b = new Button(this);
b.Text = "Button1";
b.LayoutParameters = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MatchParent, TableRow.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
row.AddView(b);

var bb = new Button(this);
bb.Text = "Button2";
bb.LayoutParameters = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MatchParent, TableRow.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
row.AddView(bb);

ll.AddView(row);
ll.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

i was doing allot of stuff that wasn't needed. but my dumbest mistake was the part where i did i =+ 1; instead of i += 1;

this is how my code looks now. its doing wat it needs to do now.

```
TableLayout ll = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.buttonLayout);
            //TableLayout llInner = new TableLayout(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
            //ll.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            //ll.LayoutParameters = lp;
            //ll.WeightSum = 2;
            //ll.AddView(llInner);
            var i = 0;
            var row = new TableRow(this);
            row.WeightSum = 2;
            //TableRow.LayoutParams rowlayout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MatchParent, TableRow.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            //row.LayoutParameters = lp;

            foreach (var series1 in series)
            {
                var b = new Button(this);
                b.Text = series1.Series;
                lp.Weight = 1;
                //lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(1, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
                b.LayoutParameters = lp;
                row.AddView(b);
                i += 1;
                if (i > 1)
                {
                    ll.AddView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent));
                    row = new TableRow(this);
                    row.LayoutParameters = lp;
                    i = 0;
                }
```

allot of stuff is commented because i've been messing around with it for a while now.